# Can't edit attributes of a toolbar in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

Working in Xcode 5 with a storyboard originally developed in Xcode 4 and the attributes of this toolbar will not modify. If I try to uncheck the Translucent attribute, it stays checked. If I change the style to default, it reverts back to black. If I choose another tint color, it reverts back to default by itself.

[image: interface builder]

I've spent hours searching for anyone else reporting this problem, but have not found a solution. As shown here, `propertyAccessControl="none"` all the way through the xml for the storyboard, so it should not be locked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="5056" systemVersion="12F45" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" initialViewController="jL0-BO-w2j">
        <dependencies>
            <deployment version="1296" defaultVersion="1296" identifier="iOS"/>
            <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3733"/>
        </dependencies>
        <scenes>
            <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="gu0-4A-nEl">
            <objects>
                <navigationController toolbarHidden="NO" id="jL0-BO-w2j" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <simulatedNavigationBarMetrics key="simulatedTopBarMetrics" barStyle="black" prompted="NO"/>
                    <simulatedToolbarMetrics key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics" barStyle="black"/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" translucent="NO" id="dbG-E3-2vd">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="-44" width="0.0" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <toolbar key="toolbar" opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" barStyle="black" id="tYf-Nn-i3a">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="436" width="320" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </toolbar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="a8f-Pc-RWZ" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="iWb-Pc-dmA"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="bVC-2G-0Rf" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-542" y="196"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Launcher Vw Ctrlr-->
        <scene sceneID="jIZ-Jl-nXT">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="a8f-Pc-RWZ" customClass="CMLauncherVwCtrlr" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="7fP-rW-Kc8">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="320" height="416"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout" bottom="YES"/>
                    <toolbarItems>
                        <barButtonItem title="Prev" id="GnE-88-jui">
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="prev:" destination="a8f-Pc-RWZ" id="DGd-03-xGA"/>
                            </connections>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </toolbarItems>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="xrV-QS-Ox8"/>
                    <simulatedNavigationBarMetrics key="simulatedTopBarMetrics" barStyle="black" prompted="NO"/>
                    <simulatedToolbarMetrics key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics" barStyle="black"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="prevButton" destination="GnE-88-jui" id="uP0-CN-ALW"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5ng-sW-JW4" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-61" y="196"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <simulatedMetricsContainer key="defaultSimulatedMetrics">
        <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="statusBar"/>
        <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation"/>
        <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination"/>
    </simulatedMetricsContainer>
</document>
```

I have found that I can set the properties programmatically, but wonder why I can't do it using Interface Builder.

Anyone else seen this behavior? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the issue is: it's me. I didn't understand how some objects relate to others. In the image in the original post, you can see that the toolbar is embedded in the navigation controller.

[image: toolbar attributes]

If I check the properties of the enclosing navigation controller, I can see that the style and translucent properties of the toolbar are actually controlled there under "Bottom Bar".

[image: navigation controller attributes]

I just need to know Interface Builder better, I guess.